# Why did I not receive the reputation bonus?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation, association-bonus

Today I started an account on askubuntu.com.  I have a 319 reputation at stackoverflow.com.  Per the docs on reputation:

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

However, I did not receive this bonus at askubuntu.com and therefore cannot comment, etc.  Am I misreading this section of the docs? I have a few other stackexchange accounts and have never received bonuses there either.

Also, in the docs:

> site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

I am not sure how this differs from the sign-up bonus mentioned above. In general, I think this section of the docs could use a bit of additional clarity, but perhaps the confusion is all on my end.

Comment: Today? Your profile there says "Member for 5 years, 11 months". As far as I know you only get the bonus when you create a new account while you have another account with at least 200 reputation.

Comment: Interesting... You currently have 319 reputation points. Your 5 most upvoted questions have, from greatest to least, 13,6,3,1 and 1 upvotes. (13 + 6 + 3 + 1 + 1) * 5 = 120, which means you gained at least 120 reputation when the question reputation amount increased from 5 points to 10 earlier this month, bringing you above the threshold of 200 points for the site association bonus. Perhaps this is a bug with how they recalculated the scores?

Comment: You didn't have 200 rep before history was changed last week.  That this revealed a bug is no great surprise.

Comment: @Tom I could have sworn I had an account at askubuntu.com but I was asked to signup today.  I guess I *did* already have an account. So then the question is why was I asked to signup again.

Comment: Looking into dark past is... anyway one possibility is one of your previous accounts associated with the same e-mail was used to sign up to that other site... and now with new account you needed to sign up and got auto-merged...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's an excellent question. According to the logs on Nov. 13:

```
Global Recalc: question upvote value change old rep = 179, new rep = 319
```

So you went from not having quite enough reputation for the association bonus to plenty. Our plan was certainly to have the association bonus applied to other sites, so this is a bug. I was able to force a recalculation on Stack Overflow, which triggered the association bonus that has been applied to your accounts on the network.

There's a chance this was a one-time thing since so much was going on with the global recalc. However, I will look into it some more to see if anyone else was affected. If it's a small number, I can fix the problem manually. Otherwise it might require a dev to solve.

Comment: I saw the update! thanks! I'll mark this as the accepted answer though it will likely not help others a whole lot.

Comment: @JonLorusso: Sure. If nothing else, this will give other users a space to let me know they have a problem.

Comment: @JonEricson I believe I have the same problem. Should I create a bug ticket or ask a new question?

Comment: @Segmentation: I recalculated your reputation and you got the association bonus too. Nick Craver [fixed the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391591/1438), but that didn't seem to fix it for you. If other people see this issue, a support ticket probably makes the most sense. (Be sure to provide link to this question!)

Comment: @JonEricson I know it's been a couple of weeks, but I also have the same problem.

Comment: @JonEricson - nevermind and/or thanks. It seems that simply joining a new stackexchange site fixed the problem. (Or the problem was fixed extremely quickly, in which case thanks.)

Answer (score 27):

**Update:** This has been completed. A fix for the backend tooling and a cleanup pass to issue missing grants has been run. 1,009 accounts have just received the bonus.

---

The bug here is an interesting consequence of our database setup. In short: we query some data from the primary, and some data from the replica. Association bonuses are one of the mechanics (along with some things like badges) that utilize the replica.

Now the way this works is, when you trip the association bonus threshold, we grant it on the other sites - this involves a query. Unfortunately, the circumstances surrounding the reputation recalc basically broke the assumption that the replica server is *reasonably* in sync. It was nowhere close.

This is my fault. When we planned out how the recalc would work technically, I failed to factor in that the recalc itself doesn't just update the `RepHistory` table (a known quantity), but also updates a field called `TargetRepChange` on the `Posts2Votes` table (the source of truth). This is a good thing, as everything is in sync, but since *the rules* changed, the data resulting from those rule calculations was updated as well. This was dozens of millions of updates I didn't factor into the costing.

The amount of transactional data we were replicating between servers was more than double what I had anticipated - this led to growth in the translation logs and a delay in replays (called "redos") on our SQL Server replicas. When the functionality to grant a bonus kicked in...it didn't think you deserved one, based on the stale data it had. That sucks, and I apologize! Luckily, this is totally fixable for all users affected (including any affected for any reason at any point in the past).

Unfortunately, the mechanism we have to grant the bonus for anyone missing it has been outgrown (e.g., it's timing out - I just tried it). It has 2 modes: “simulation” and "do the grants" mode. I need to fix the simulation for streaming output so I can sanity check it before smashing go (although I'm ~99% confident it'd work fine...let's not make a bigger mess).

**I plan to fix this up Monday** and will get all missing association bonuses granted. I'll update this post once it's done :)

Comment: [More trouble...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391726/reputation-bonus-removed).

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340026/bug-in-account-reputation-association

Comment: Nick, is this the same issue, re-surfacing? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341944/have-multiple-site-accounts-and-enough-reputation-to-qualify-for-the-association