# Reputation Bonus Removed

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-graph, association-bonus

Before I begin, I have a similar issue with this question [Why did I not receive the reputation bonus?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391583/why-did-i-not-receive-the-reputation-bonus) from [Jon Lorusso](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/291892/jon-lorusso).

I also got the +100 reputation bonus on every platform, but the 100 reputation has been removed from my  [Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606441/valkon).

I had 409 reputation before the bonus and then for a couple of minutes it stayed as 509. As you can see below, I captured it the moment I got the bonus.[image]

And now I am on 409 reputation again, but on the graph it cleary states that I have 509. As you can see here.

[image]

And reputation from https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't have had the bonus on SO anyway.

Comment: @DavidG I see, I am not asking for the bonus anyway. I saw the developer's response on the linked question that he worked on a bug, I believe that this is a bug as well since my graph is wrong. If the graph also had the same value, I wouldn't mind.

Comment: Yeah, not saying it's not a bug, there's definitely something peculiar going on here. Maybe they're running another recalc. Either that or there may be a [caching issue](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: @DavidG per my reading of the [bonus FAQ at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/165773) it applies to all sites, including one where user has got initial 200 rep. That is, SO account should have gotten +100, just like all other accounts

Comment: the graph is updated each day, it will only show you until yesterday

Comment: Looks like a case of bugs compounding bugs.  [This happened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391591/17034) to your account, that screwed up the graph.  I pinged the SO dev to let him know.  Use stackoverflow.com/reputation to audit your account, looks okay to me.

Comment: @HansPassant Great, so based on that I have 509. I guess it's indeed a bug.

Comment: The reputation graph would look like that if you had a post deleted for being spam/abusive, plus that would explain the missing 100 reputation. Check your [detailed rep history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606441/valkon?tab=reputation) to see if this is the case (only you and mods would be able to see this).

Comment: @Laurel, I checked the reputation from the link that Hans Passant provided and it states that I have 509 reputation. Also, my graph showed 409 reputation before, so it definitely changed when I received 100 reputation.

Comment: i have witnessed the same and [asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391331/rep-decreasing-without-a-cause) and was abolished ...

Comment: There’s a reputation recalculation each night and that seems to have solved your problem. You’re back up in the 500s.

Comment: @Catija Great, I have to say that my intention wasn't to get back the reputation, it was just to report my experience in case it was a bug.